# Problem when including file

Tags: php

```
<?php

//this is intializer.php
defined('DS')?  null :define('DS',DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

defined('SITE_ROOT')? null :
        define('SITE_ROOT',DS.'C:',DS.'wamp',DS.'www',DS.'photo_gallery');

defined('LIB_PATH')?null:define('LIB_PATH',SITE_ROOT.DS.'includes');

require_once(LIB_PATH.DS.'datainfo.php');
require_once(LIB_PATH.DS.'function.php');
require_once(LIB_PATH.DS.'session.php');
require_once(LIB_PATH.DS.'database.php');
require_once(LIB_PATH.DS.'user.php');


//this is other file where i call php file

// ERROR Use of undefined constant LIB_PATH - assumed 'LIB_PATH' in     
//C:\wamp\www\photo_gallery\includes\database.php  on 

//Notice: Use of undefined constant DS - assumed 'DS' in   
//C:\wamp\www\photo_gallery\includes\database.php on 

include(LIB_PATH.DS."database.php")

?>
```

Any ideas as to what might be causing the error above? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't directly related to your question, but

```
define('SITE_ROOT',DS.'C:',DS.'wamp',DS.'www',DS.'photo_gallery');
```

should probably be

```
define('SITE_ROOT',DS.'C:'.DS.'wamp'.DS.'www'.DS.'photo_gallery');
```

Comment: i really thankful to recorrect me thanks any way
define('SITE_ROOT','C:'.DS.'wamp'.DS.'www'.DS.'photo_gallery');
i eliminated one   DS.'c:' and write down to ('site_root','C:')

Answer (score 2):

You need to do this:

`defined('SITE_ROOT')? null :`     `define('SITE_ROOT','C:'.DS.'wamp'.DS.'www',DS.'photo_gallery');`

You don't need a `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` before the start of your site root.

You might be better off with this:

`defined('SITE_ROOT')? null : define('SITE_ROOT', dirname(__FILE__));`

As long as **intializer.php** is in the root directory

Answer (score 1):

You have to add this line in the `database.php`

```
require_once("../../includes/initialise.php");
```

and remove

```
require_once (LIB_PATH.DS."config.php");
```

because the constant `LIB_PATH` and `DS` are not accesible unles you add the following code

```
require_once (LIB_PATH.DS."config.php");
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I think what you are looking for is the actual **system file path**. To get that you can echo

```
dirname( __FILE__ );
```

You can do this in any file that you want and it will display the system file path relative to your file. For me it's something like this:

```
/home2/myusername/public_html/project_name/includes/config.php
```

so if you are interested in the "project_name" folder you should have something like this:

```
defined("SITE_ROOT") ? null : define("SITE_ROOT", DS . "home2" . DS . "myusername" . DS . "public_html" . DS . "project_name" );
```

Then if you are looking for the "includes" folder which will be your library you should have something like this:

```
defined("LIB_PATH")  ? null : define("LIB_PATH", SITE_ROOT . DS . "includes" );
```

Hope this helps. I had the exact same problem and this worked for me.

Cheers,
Mihai Popa